# Train and validation sets splits using load_data

Tags: python, dataset, huggingface

I'm using the package "datasets". The code I have:

```
squad_v2 = True
model_checkpoint = "roberta-base"
batch_size = 10

from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric
datasets = load_dataset("squad_v2")
datasets
```

and output:

[image]

It's working fine, but as the dataset really huge is a lack of memory on the gpu during the training model. Is there any way how to using "load_dataset" make train and validations splits smaller? But still to have them both on "datasets"?